# ld searching in the wrong path, and searching for the wrong library

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linker, ld

I am trying to compile wireshark on my machine because I have some custom plugins I need to add with it. When I run `make install`, I get the message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwsutil
```

Running the command `ld -lwsutil --verbose` gives (the last few lines)

```
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwsutil.so failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwsutil.a failed
attempt to open //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwsutil.so failed
attempt to open //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwsutil.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwsutil.so failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwsutil.a failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib64/libwsutil.so failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib64/libwsutil.a failed
attempt to open //lib64/libwsutil.so failed
attempt to open //lib64/libwsutil.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib64/libwsutil.so failed
attempt to open //usr/lib64/libwsutil.a failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/libwsutil.so failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/libwsutil.a failed
attempt to open //lib/libwsutil.so failed
attempt to open //lib/libwsutil.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/libwsutil.so failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/libwsutil.a failed
attempt to open //usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/libwsutil.so failed
attempt to open //usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/libwsutil.a failed
attempt to open //usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/libwsutil.so failed
attempt to open //usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/libwsutil.a failed
```

Two things I can see from here: there is an extra slash on the directory it attempts to open (is this fine?)
The directory is wrong: I can see wsutil in `/usr/local/lib`
Also the files that it tries to look for is wrong - for wsutil the files are:

```
libwsutil
libwsutil.3
libwsutil.3.0.0
libwsutil.la
```

Where should I start to fix these?

UPDATE: Running `ls -lh /usr/local/lib/libwsutil*` gives

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 Sep  8 11:22 /usr/local/lib/libwsutil -> libwsutil.3.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 Sep  8 11:22 /usr/local/lib/libwsutil.3 -> libwsutil.3.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 65K Sep  8 11:22 /usr/local/lib/libwsutil.3.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 866 Sep  8 11:22 /usr/local/lib/libwsutil.la
```

Also the version of wireshark which I am installing is 1.10.8, on Ubuntu 16.04.

Another thing to add: I don't have a `lib64` directory under `/usr/local/` (only lib exists). When I execute arch it gives me `x86_64`

Comment: Can you update your question to include the output of `ls -lh /usr/local/lib/libwsutil*`?

Comment: @redneb Updated

Comment: There should have been a `*.so` file in there, that's what `ld` is looking for. How did you install wireshark (which I believe provides that library)? Maybe you could try to reinstall it with the package manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install libswutil from package, if you have no special reason to build yourself.

```
apt-get install libwsutil-dev
```

Wireshark is also available in package, and you don't need any dev packages:

```
apt-get install wireshark
```

Most of the custom plugins were written in Lua, so you don't have to compile wireshark at all.